# Page not showing single database entry in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have set up my app with Iron Router and have a 'post' page where I would like to show a single post according to its ID. However, this page does not show a post, and instead the post template renders blank (although the url and nav are working fine). Here is my code:

router.js

```
Router.route('postDetail', {
  path: '/posts/:_id',
  notFoundTemplate: 'postNotFound',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('post')
    ]
  },
  data: function() {
    var idVar = this.params._id
    return posts.findOne({_id: idVar});
  }
});
```

postDetail.html

```
<template name="postDetail">
    {{address}}
</template>
```

postsPub.js

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function () {
  return posts.find();
});

Meteor.publish('post', function (id) {
  return posts.find(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your publisher needs an `id`. Try this in your `waitOn`:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id)
```

Comment: This causes the template to endlessly show "loading..." Perhaps my publish code is completely wrong? I simply want to be able to show a post individually >.>

Comment: Do you get any errors on the command line? Are you sure it's `posts` and not `Posts`? I'm asking because if your publisher throws an error, you'd get that behavior on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by simply removing the 'post' publish function, and including the following route which refers to the 'posts' publish function instead:

```
Router.route('postDetail', {
  path: '/posts/:_id',
  notFoundTemplate: 'postNotFound',
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); },
  data: function() { return posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

Comment: If you removed post publish, that means you are using autopublish package. Remove this package. Using this package is unsafe.

Comment: I don't have auto publish installed. It's just that now I am subscribing to 'posts' instead of post.